# Ошибка в селекторе кнопки - нет округлости кнопки

Tags: android, ui

Есть стандартная кнопка, в backgound добавил @drawable/selector_dark Цвет у кнопки меняется, но нет закругления на углах, подскажите пожалуйста, что ни так?

Вот XML @drawable/selector_dark

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDarkLight">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

На всякий случай XML activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"
    tools:context="com.example.user.scan.MainActivity"
    android:background="#28313C"
    android:paddingTop="40dp"
    android:paddingBottom="40dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:text="Новая инвентаризация"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_dark"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

        <Button
            android:text="Список инвентаризаций"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_dark"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

        <Button
            android:text="Загрузить данные"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_dark"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

        <Button
            android:text="Настройки"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_dark"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

        <Button
            android:text="Тест сканера"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_dark"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Исправил селектор, все заработало

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:startColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="@color/colorPrimaryDarkLight" android:startColor="@color/colorPrimaryDarkLight" />
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```